# Select only text of an element (not the text of its children/descendants)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please consider the following HTML:

```
<td>
  Some Text
  <table>.....</table>
</td>
```

I need to manipulate the "Some Text" text of `td` element. I should not touch the table element inside of this `td`.

So, just for example, maybe I want to replace all "e" with "@".  I tried a few approaches with jQuery's .text() and .html().  I seem to always select something from within the child table, which I shouldn't touch.  Also, unfortunately, I cannot wrap "Some Text" into a span or a div.

Comment: I'm not sure why Karim deleted his answer, so I'm placing this in a comment. What's wrong with `$('#myCell')[0].firstChild.data = $('#x')[0].firstChild.data.replace('e', '@');`. The only thing I can see is it might not inculde all text objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $('td').contents().each(function(){
     if(this.nodeType === 3)
      $(this).replaceWith(this.wholeText.replace(/e/g, '#'));
  });
});
```

or like you suggested

```
$('td').contents().each(function(){
  if(this.nodeType === 3)
     this.data = this.wholeText.replace(/e/g, '#');
 });
```

`.contents()` delivers **all** elements, **textNodes** included.

Comment: Thank you, jAndy.  I'm having trouble setting text to it's new value.  The .text('new value') just doesn't do anything.

Comment: @dimskiy: indeed, `.replaceWith()` does also perform well.

Comment: I had a hard time choosing between the 2 solutions.  Choosing yours for .replaceWith().  I actually have cases where certain chars need to be replaced by html elements, and .replaceWith() does the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do something for *each* piece of text in the td, you could just iterate over them with a loop:

```
var nodes=tdEl.childNodes;
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; ++i){
  if(nodes[i].nodeType===3){  // 3 means "text"
    nodes[i].data = nodes[i].wholeText.replace(/e/g, '@');
  }
}
```

Did I understand what you were looking for correctly?

You could use jQuery if you're already loading it for other stuff, but I wouldn't load in a 24kb library for the small bit of code above.

Comment: Thank you, lucideer.  I have jQuery already in that project, so a jQuery solution is fine as well.  I can't set text using .wholeText.  I get 
Error: setting a property that has only a getter

Comment: Update:  nodes[i].data  will render html tags as text.

Comment: Sorry about that dimskiy - you're right, my reply was incorrect about setting the wholeText - edited. You can't put HTMLElements into a textNode, but you can remove the textNode and replace it with a HTMLElement (or a series of them).