# jQuery selector for first text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

yes, agree that I should have figured this out from the doc, but no - I could not :-(

```
<div id="jalla">
    <span>
        <span class="ui-btn-text">
            I need this text
            <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status">
                click to collapse contents
            </span>
        </span>
    <span>
</div>
```

How to simply select (and update) the text "I need this text". This is one of the things I've tried:

```
notWorking = $('.ui-btn-text').text();
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268556/javascript-select-only-text-of-an-element-not-its-children). Is also the first result on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=select+only+text+of+element).

Comment: I formatted your code and it seems you are missing a `</span>` or have one `<span>` too much. You might want to correct that.

Comment: @Phrogz he is asking to get the first text only element, which is what that question is. Besides this question being a `span`, and the other a `td` they are the same. Both questions are manipulating the text of embedded elements.

Comment: @Chad - Sorry, should have found that. Thanks for providing the link

Comment: @FelixKling - Thanks for formatting and pointing out. Now corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes jQuery is not the best answer. In this case the [HTML DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1451460987) makes it easier.

```
var span = document.querySelector('.ui-btn-text'); // first item with this class
var text = span.childNodes[0];                     // an actual text node
text.nodeValue = "Changed!"                        // done!
```

Seen in action: http://jsfiddle.net/C7Q6K/

**Edit**: For older browsers, you could use jQuery to get the `span` itself:

```
var span = $('.ui-btn-text')[0];  // get the DOM element, not the jQuery object
span.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Changed!";
```

Comment: What would you use in browsers which do not support `.querySelector()`?

Comment: @Chad 24 seconds too late! :)

Comment: Nice, I also got it wrong at the first place. here is jsfiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/gagan/6CxBU/