# JQuery selecting text in parent div

Tags: jquery, html, select, each

I currently have the following

```
<div class ="parent">
  <div class="inner">Hello
    <div>Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class ="parent">
  <div class="inner">Hello
    <div>Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am currently using `$(div.parent).each(function(index,item)` to iterate through each parent which works perfectly.

My problem is that I need to select the word hello. I am currently using `$(item).text()` but it is always returning HelloGoodBye which is a problem. I need to ignore any other div.

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: See this post, maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268556/select-only-text-of-an-element-not-the-text-of-its-children-descendants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('div.parent').not('.parent .inner div').each(function(index,item)
```

Alternately

```
$(div.parent:not('.inner div').each(function(index,item)
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. However it may due to the DiV's being replaced at some point. For example, the Div called 'inner' may be replaced with a div that does not have a class name

Comment: This isn't going to work. `$(item).text();` will still pull the text from the final div.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `jQuery.text()` method, I'm going to recommend finding the first `childNode` which will be that textnode you're looking for:

```
​var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('inner'),
    i = 0;
for (i = divs.length; i--;) {
  console.log(divs[i].childNodes[0]);   
}
```

OR

```
var divs = $('.inner');
divs.each(function() {
  console.log(this.childNodes[0]);
});
```

Keep in mind that the `childNodes` method will not be recognized by jQuery.

Comment: Good answer Nick. And as an addition [here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/966Wx/).

Answer (score 0):

The subject has been discussed before here with bunch of suitable solutions: [Using .text() to retrieve only text not nested in child tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by cloning each element, removing the unwanted div and then grabbing the text.

```
$('div.parent div.inner').each(function(index,item) {
    $this = $(item).clone();
    $this = $this.find('div').remove();
    $this.text();
});​
```

Here is a JS Fiddle with the code and HTML above in action: http://jsfiddle.net/L8T7s/