# How can I change style of a defined keyword without explicit markup.

Tags: html, css, keyword, markup

In a website, is there any way of changing text attribute of keyword, like product name, in an entire website without using any kind of html tags wrapped around those instances? I may require to define those keywords in server side environment or there may be a server side  script in which I may need to define. Or can we use client side Javascript like some jquery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript on the client side to achieve this.
Drawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268601/1470607) the following is a simple example:

[**Sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5mGce/)

JS:

```
$('*').contents().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeType === 3) {
        $(this).replaceWith(this.wholeText.replace(/target/g, 'replaced'));    
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<h1>target</h1>
<p>Here it is: <span>target</span> and target</p>
```

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem. I can add span tag with some css class through this replace function. 

$(this).replaceWith(this.wholeText.replace(/target/g, '<span style="color: #f00">Target</span>'));

I was exactly looking for this functionality. Thanks a lot.